# Audio Stream Not playing in smart phone

Tags: android, html, audio, streaming, audio-streaming

Iam trying to built an android application for playing online radio. The code is working in emulator properly. but when installed in phone it does not works.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
String url = "http://5293.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/JACK2_LOWAAC_SC";
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Is there any problem in the link format? I tried to play same link in html5 its working fine on desktop but the same website when opened in phone the link is not working. Also are there any issues or any components in html5 which do not work in smart  phones bu work on Desktop ?
 I need to play the live stream not the static file like mp3. You can take some URL form www.listenlive.eu/uk.html and try to play.The URL in my code is form this site only. download the VLC file and open it with any text editor and you will get url.

Answer (score 0):

use   mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); instead of mediaPlayer.prepare(); since your are streaming from web and also add permission for internet

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Also

```
String url = "http://5293.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/JACK2_LOWAAC_SC";
```

doesn't work for me instead i use

```
 final String url = "http://vprmix.streamguys.net/vprmix64.mp3";
```

private boolean isPLAYING = false;

```
     public void streamAudio(String url) {

        if (!isPLAYING) {
            isPLAYING = true;
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
               mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("mediaPlayer", "prepare() failed");
            }
        } else {
            isPLAYING = false;
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But i need to play the live stream not the static file like mp3. Can you please take some URL form [www.listenlive.eu/uk.html](http://www.listenlive.eu/uk.html) and try to play.The above URL is form this site only. download the VLC file and open it with any text editor you will get url